# how to change code of d3.js pie chart in .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I am new in d3.js. I am trying to make a simle pie chart program. I made a seperated pie.js file in which I wrote pie chart code. I linked that to html file chart.html. Its works !

**problem** : I want to change pie chart value through manually in chart.html page. Like when pir chart load in html file i want to modify value just before that.

Can any body suggest me what should I need to do?

chart.html

       `<html lang="en">
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>D3: Pie layout</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/pie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>`

pie.js
`

```
        //Width and height
        var w = 300;
        var h = 300;

        var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ];

        var outerRadius = w / 2;
        var innerRadius = 0;
        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                        .innerRadius(innerRadius)
                        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie();

        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Set up groups
        var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
                      .data(pie(dataset))
                      .enter()
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("class", "arc")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");

        //Draw arc paths
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .attr("d", arc);

        //Labels
        arcs.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });
```

`

Comment: It is unclear to me exactly what you are trying to accomplish, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Josh i want to say that when pie chart about to display on html, can i am able to change its dataset value in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy. just put the dataset before the file load.it will work.

`<script> dataset=[1,2,3,4];</script>
<script> your link <script>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3: Pie layout</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>dataset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/pie.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Remove var dataset = [ 5, 10, 20, 45, 6, 25 ]; from the file.